# Terraform error when applying only a certain tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, count, terraform, tags

I'm trying to add the tag "Project" to the resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" to make it match the rest of the resources in this project, but when I do so Terraform throws an error.

Relevant Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway" "tgw" {
  description = "TGW for inter-region connectivity"
  auto_accept_shared_attachments = "disable"
  default_route_table_association = "disable"
  default_route_table_propagation = "disable"
  dns_support = "enable"
  tags = {
    "Name" = "labs tgw",
    "Terraform" = "true",
    "Project"   = var.project_id
}
}

## Create new TGW Attachments 
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "tgw_attachments" {
    subnet_ids = aws_subnet.tgw[*].id
    transit_gateway_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw.id
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    dns_support = "enable"
    transit_gateway_default_route_table_association = "false"
    transit_gateway_default_route_table_propagation = "false"
    tags = {
    "Name" = "labs_tgw_attachment",
    "Terraform" = "true",
    #"Project"   = var.project_id  
  }

}
## Accept attachment if it hasn't already been accepted
data "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_attachment" "attachment_data" {
  transit_gateway_attachment_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.tgw_attachments.id 
  
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment_accepter" "accept" {
  count = (data.aws_ec2_transit_gateway_attachment.attachment_data.state == "pendingAcceptance") ? 1 : 0
  transit_gateway_attachment_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.tgw_attachments.id

  depends_on = [
    aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.tgw_attachments
  ]
}
```

The purpose of the data block and count is due to terraform throwing an error that the attachment is in an inconsistent state after it's already been accepted, so it checks to see if the attachment is in "pendingAcceptance" state, and builds the accepter only if that's true.

Currently, the attachment is accepted, everything else is working as expected, but if I uncomment `"Project" = var.project_id`, then I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid count argument
│ 
│   on modules/main.tf line 74, in resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment_accepter" "accept":
│   74:   count = (data.aws_ec2_transit_gateway_attachment.attachment_data.state == "pendingAcceptance") ? 1 : 0
│ 
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count depends on.
```

I've tried adding the tags with merge, like so:

```
tags = merge({
    "Name" = "labs tgw attachment",
    "Terraform" = "true"
    },
    {
    "Project" = var.project_id
    }
  )
}
```

But got the same error, presumably since that formatting isn't required and doesn't really change the way the tags are evaluated.

Comment: The error is clear "use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count depends on". Not sure what exactly are you asking for then?